# How many queries per second is my Postgres executing?

Tags: postgresql

How can I tell how many queries per second my Postgres database is executing?

Comment: Have you checked out: http://serverfault.com/questions/268506/how-to-check-throughput-query-per-second-of-a-database

Comment: @thtsigma Doesn't answer this question. Queries stats for MySQL, only transaction stats for PG.

Comment: Have you tried any Postgres profiling tools, such as [pg_top](https://github.com/markwkm/pg_top)?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW
e.g. select tup_inserted from pg_stat_database

Comment: I provided a script for doing a similar calculation on another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73569756/1714997

Answer (score 24):

Use this query to read total number of **transactions** executed in all databases:

```
SELECT sum(xact_commit+xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database;
```

If you want the same counter for just one database, use:

```
SELECT xact_commit+xact_rollback FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = 'mydb';
```

To calculate TPS (transactions per second), run the query several times and calculate difference over time interval.

There are ready made tools for that, one of them is http://bucardo.org/wiki/Check_postgres

More info: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW

---

**Update:** Konrad corrected my misunderstanding of his question. The goal was to count queries, not transactions.

How to count queries?

**Method 1**

Use [pg_stat_statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) contrib.

**Method 2**

Enable full logging of queries for a representative period of time.

To enable full logging, for PostgreSQL 9.0 - 9.3, change following settings in `postgresql.conf`

```
logging_collector = on
log_line_prefix = '%t '
log_rotation_size = 1GB
log_statement = all
```

If you want to see also query duration, you can set `log_min_duration_statement = 0` **instead** of `log_statement = all`. This is very useful for query tuning.

Then reload config (restart or HUP) and collect enough log to estimate traffic.

**Note:** neither method will include queries embedded in user-defined functions.

Comment: I know how to calculate transactions per second. The question is about queries per second specifically. One transaction can have 0 or more queries.

Comment: @KonradGarus How do you have a transaction with 0 queries?

Comment: fencepost error? `begin;rollback;` is how many?